# How can I tell Flash Builder to debug a SWF in a new browser window?

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome

In this case it's Chrome. I've had a look at [Chrome's command line switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) and the one I'd need Flash Builder/eclipse to fire is --new-window. Makes sense of course.

So I go into Flash builder, go to the browser preferences and set the parameters for the Chrome bin app, like so:[image: This image shows the Flash Builder browser config panel]

So that, to me seems right, but it doesn't do what it says on the tin. So what am I doing wrong and how can I get it to launch in a new window?

Comment: Have you also tried the option `--user-data-dir=/tmp/XXX` (with XXX some new, blank directory)? However, I don't know if forcing a new profile will affect your Flash plugin of choice (assuming you're running the Adobe Flash debugger plugin as configured in about:config).

Comment: PS from [Chromium switches how-to page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags): "It is important to note that using these switches is not supported or recommended. They should only be used for temporary cases and may break in the future."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MacOS X, Chrome only starts once. So, with your startup options, you get this error:

```
Unable to obtain profile lock.
```

The origin of this error is [explained here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=22163).

A solution is to use a different data dir for your debugging sessions:

```
--user-data-dir=<PATH TO DATA DIR>
```

For example in your home directory (something like /Users/username/chrome-debug-datadir). That solved the problem here.
You need to configure Chrome once in the new data dir. It also gives a clean separation between developing / debugging sessions and regular Chrome sessions.